# in a group presentation, any (ex-post) relation can be obtained as an elment of the normal closure of a (prior) "maximal" set of relators?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $S \subseteq G $ a subset that generates $G$, $R \subseteq F_S$, where $F_S$ is the free group on the set $S$.

Let $\psi: F_S \rightarrow G$ be a group homomorphism, s.t. $\psi(s) = s, \forall s \in S$ and $\psi(r) = e_G, \forall r \in R$

Suppose that $R$ is a *maximal set of relators* for $G$, meaning the following:

$\forall T \subseteq F_S, R \subseteq T,$ s.t. $\forall t \in T, \psi(t) = e_G,$ $\forall \phi:F_S \rightarrow H,$

with $H$ group and $\phi$ a group homormophism, then:

$$(\forall r \in R, \phi(r) = e_H) \Rightarrow (\forall t \in T, \phi(t) = e_H)$$

Then, under these conditions, is it true that the following holds?

$\forall \xi:F_S \rightarrow K$, with $K$ a group and $\xi$ s group homormophism, s.t. $\forall y \in F_S, \psi(y) = e_G \Longleftrightarrow \xi(y) = e_K $ then:

$\forall x \in F_S, \xi(x) = e_K \Longleftrightarrow x \in \langle R^{F_S} \rangle$

If true, is there a simple way to show it?

Comment: Use `$\langle X\mid R\rangle$` for $\langle X\mid R\rangle$.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "infer ex post"?  I suspect that if you write down a precise definition of this you will find that your question is trivial from the definitions.

Comment: It's not clear to me either, @EricWofsey. I suggest you vote to close.

Comment: I agree that the OP should clarify these issues, but they seem to be asking if every word $r$ in the group generators that represents the identity element of $G$ can be written in the free group $F$ as a product of conjugates of elements of $R$. The answer to that is yes, by definition. But it is worth remarking that the problem of expressing $r$ in this way can be computationally very difficult - much more difficult than proving hat $r=_G 1$ - i.e. the constructive word problem can be provably arbitrarily more difficult than the word problem itself.

Comment: Your final statement about $\xi$ at the end doesn't seem like what you want.  What is $R^K$?  And presumably you want some hypothesis on $\xi$ that relates it to $R$ somehow.

Comment: Isn't what you are calling a maximal set of relators of $G$ the same as a set of defining relators?

Comment: @EricWofsey I think I know what you mean. Perhaps I should rephrase it like this:
$\forall \xi:F_S \rightarrow K$, with $K$ a group and $\xi$ s group homormophism, s.t. **$\forall y \in F_S, \psi(y) = e_G \Longleftrightarrow \xi(y) = e_K$** then: 

$\forall x \in F_S$ s.t. $\xi(x) = e_K \Rightarrow x \in$ **$\langle R^{F_S} \rangle$**

Comment: @DerekHolt For your second comment, I guess so. But in the end, this is what I wanted a justification for. On first comment, your interpretation of my original OP is correct - with the exception that when you say that "every word that represents the element of G", I am not thinking necessarily of $G = <S|R>$, but of any group $H$ generated by $S$ s.t. any relation $r = e_H$ with $r \in F_S$ seen in $H$ can be *logically* inferred from $\{r = e_H: r \in R\}$, so that $R$ is a *maximal* set of relators - or a set of *defining relators*, as you say

Comment: It seems to me that the group $H$ that you are describing is unique and is precisely $\langle X \mid R \rangle$.

Comment: @DerekHolt to add on top, what I am really trying to convince my self is that if in any group $H$, a relation $r = e_H$ (or also $r \neq e_H$) can be inferred *logically* from a set of defining relations \{r_i = e_H: r\in R\}, then in fact $r = e_H$ can be inferred *algebrically* by rewriting $r$ as a product of conjugates $gr_ig^{-1}$ - so that each $grg^{-1}=e_H$. *a-priori* we could have an element $x=x_1...x_k, x_i \in H$, s.t. $x=e_H$, but $x$ that cannot be written as product of conjugates of $r_i$. *ex post*, this cannot be the case. the why is what I was finding a justification for.

Comment: @DerekHolt on your third comment, probably so. But the why, is what I wanted to find a proof. Also, I understand my first OP was be a bit confusing - e.g. it was not clear what an *ex post* relation means. So, I have rephrased it to formalize it and clarify my ask.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand what you are asking now.

If  $r \not\in \langle R^{F_S} \rangle$, then $r$ maps onto a nontrivial element of the group $G:=F_S/\langle R^{F_S} \rangle$, and so $G$ is a group in which the words in $R$ all map onto the identity element, but $r$ does not.

So, if the assumption that all elements of $R$ map onto the identity of a group $H$ implies that $r$ maps onto the identity of $H$, then we must have $r \in \langle R^{F_S} \rangle$, which means that $r$ is equal in $F_S$ to a product of conjugates of elements of $R$.